# Create instance using terrafrom from GCP marketplace

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I m trying to create [terraform script](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/compute_instance_template.html) to launch the [fastai instance](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/click-to-deploy-images/deeplearning) from the marketplace.

I m adding image name as,

```
boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = "<image name>"
    }
  }
```

When I add

```
click-to-deploy-images/deeplearning
```

from url

```
https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/click-to-deploy-images/deeplearning
```

is giving error,

```
Error: Error resolving image name 'click-to-deploy-images/deeplearning': Could not find image or family click-to-deploy-images/deeplearning

  on fastai.tf line 13, in resource "google_compute_instance" "default":
  13: resource "google_compute_instance" "default" {
```

If I use

```
debian-cloud/debian-9
```

from url

```
https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/debian-cloud/debian-stretch?project=<>
```

is working.

Can we deploy fastai image through terraform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case, the name was "deeplearning-platform-release/pytorch-latest-gpu",

```
boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = "deeplearning-platform-release/pytorch-latest-gpu"
      ...
    }
  }
```

Now I m able to create the instance.

Answer (score 1):

I made a deployment from the deep learning marketplace VM instance you share and review the source image[1], you should be able to use that url I provided to deploy with Terraform. I also notice a warning image stating that image is deprecated and there is this new version[2].

Hope this helps!

[1]sourceImage: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/click-to-deploy-images/global/images/tf2-2-1-cu101-20200109

[2]https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/click-to-deploy-images/global/images/tf2-2-1-cu101-20200124

Comment: hi. I m getting 401 after clicking on those links. How can I resolve the 401 error.? any idea?

Answer (score 1):

To other newbies like me:

Apparently GCP Marketplace is using [Deployment Manager](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/deployment-manager-and-cloud-marketplace) which is google's own declarative tool to manage infrastructure. (I think `module`s are the closest abstraction in `terraform` to it.)

Hence, there is no simple/single answer to the question in the title.

In my opinion - if you start from scratch and/or can afford the effort the time - the best is to use `terraform` modules instead of GCP marketplace solutions - if such exists.

However, changes are good that you are importing an existing infra and you cannot just replace it immediately (or there is no such module).

In this case, I think the best that you can do is go to [Deployment Manager in google console](https://console.cloud.google.com/dm/deployments) and open the particular deployment you need to import.

At this point you can see what resources make up the deployment. Probably there will be `vm template`(s), `vm`(s), `firewall rule`(s), etc...

Clicking on `vm instance` and the `template` will show you a lot of useful details.

Most importantly you can deduce what image was used.

E.g.:
In my case it showed:

```
sourceImage https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/openvpn-access-server-200800/global/images/aspub275
```

From this I could define (based on [an answer](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/issues/7319#issuecomment-696811769) on issue [#7319](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/issues/7319))

```
data "google_compute_image" "openvpn_server" {
  name    = "aspub275"
  project = "openvpn-access-server-200800"
}
```

Which I could in turn use in `google_compute_instance` resource.

This will force a recreation of the VM though.

Comment: also, there is https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/deployment_manager_deployment

but starts with a huge warning sign...