# how to declare gcp compute engine images from gcp marketplace through terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, terraform-provider-gcp, gcp-ai-platform-training

I've a request in company to write a terraform script to deploy a compute engine image from GCP marketplace? This is most likely a deep-learning image. Can anyone please help?

Example image - https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/click-to-deploy-images/deeplearning?q=compute%20engine%20images&id=8857b4a3-f60f-40b2-9b32-22b4428fd256

Comment: Does this put you in the right direction ?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60510796/create-instance-using-terrafrom-from-gcp-marketplace

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at the following examples [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ai-platform-samples/tree/master/notebooks/tools/terraform)

```
resource "random_id" "instance_id" {
  byte_length = 8
}

resource "google_compute_instance" "default" {
  name         = "vm-${random_id.instance_id.hex}"
  machine_type = var.instance_type
  zone         = var.zone

  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = "deeplearning-platform-release/tf-ent-latest-gpu" # TensorFlow Enterprise
      size  = 50                                                // 50 GB Storage
    }
  }

  network_interface {
    network = "default"
    access_config {}
  }

  guest_accelerator {
    type  = var.gpu_type
    count = var.gpu_count
  }

  scheduling {
    automatic_restart   = true
    on_host_maintenance = "TERMINATE"
  }

  metadata = {
    install-nvidia-driver = "True"
    proxy-mode            = "service_account"
  }

  tags = ["deeplearning-vm"]

  service_account {
    scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"]
  }
}
```

I recently added support for AI Platform Notebooks in Terraform as [well](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/notebooks_instance.html).