# How can I programmatically create the WURFL service from GCP marketplace?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, wurfl, google-cloud-marketplace

I would like to use ScientiaMobile’s WURFL Microservice for GCP Marketplace (https://docs.scientiamobile.com/documentation/wurfl-microservice/gcp-getting-started) however I do not want to create it via GCPs’s console UI because I want to programmatically destroy the instance when it’s not being used then programmatically create it again when needed. In other words, I want to write a script to create it.

Is it possible to programmatically create services from GCP’s marketplace?

Comment: Under the covers, Google Marketplace applications deploy via Deployment Manager. Once you deploy, you should be able to use the Deployment Manager APIs to destroy the deployment. I think you can also access the Deployment Manager configuration file (after deployment) which would allow you to deploy and destroy via program control.

Comment: Great stuff. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can either use Deployment Manager or Terraform for your use case. If you're only deploying workloads to GCP, Deployment Manager should meet all of your deployment needs. And because it's a built-in Google Cloud tool, it's also easier to use from an authentication perspective. You can learn more about this technology by visiting the official documentation and guide for [Deployment Manager](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/quickstart).

On the other hand, Terraform is a better option when deploying to multiple cloud providers or vendors. There are also plenty of community tutorials for Terraform on Google Cloud, check this [link](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/getting-started-on-gcp-with-terraform) to know more.

Comment: Thanks, we already use terraform extensively but prior to posting the question above I couldn't find a resource in the GCP Terraform provider that is capable of deploying stuff from MarketPlace. Do you know of a provider that is capable of deploying Marketplace resources?

Comment: You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60510796/create-instance-using-terrafrom-from-gcp-marketplace) article and see if it helps.