# Automated deployment the F5 BIG-IP on Google Cloud Platform (GCP)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, f5

We are trying to deploy the F5 BIG-IP on Google Cloud Platform through Terraform.

Please suggest any reference articles to accomplish the activity.

Comment: I assume that you want to deploy the F5 BIG-IP from the GCP Marketplace. Have you checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60510796/create-instance-using-terrafrom-from-gcp-marketplace)?

Comment: Yes we can deploy it through GCP Marketplace, but our requirement is it should be done via Terraform.

Comment: As you could notice at [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60510796/create-instance-using-terrafrom-from-gcp-marketplace), I recommended to you, **there's no easy way to do it because GCP Marketplace rely on GCP [Deployment Manager](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/deployment-manager-and-cloud-marketplace)**. You can try to do the same workaround and find the source image for F5 BIG-IP.